# Changing the order used to show the weekdays

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I have installed the event calendar module.

The problem that I have is that the calendar block outputs as follows:

> S M T W T F S

where I would like it to be outputted as follows:

> M T W T F S S

I've tried looking at other sources but I cannot seem to find a solution.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully that module integrates with the rest of the system properly - if it does, you can go to /admin/config/regional/settings and change "First day of week" to Monday.

Comment: Brilliant. Would of never of guessed to go there. I didn't think it would use a global variable to congregate information and output the calendar. Thanks for the quick response. Will mark this as the answer in due course.